# If $f(y)=\limsup_k\|y-x_k\|^2$ then $f$ is a strictly convex function

Tags: convex-analysis, convex-optimization

Let $y \in \mathbb{R^n}$, and $(x_k)_{k\in \mathbb{N}}$ a sequence in $ \mathbb{R^n}$ and $f(y)=\limsup_k\|y-x_k\|^2$ ($\|{\cdot}\|$ is the euclidean norm).

Then $f$ is a convex function.

But how can we prove that $f$ is a **strictly** convex function ?

Comment: $f(y)$ could be $\infty$ everywhere

Comment: Why don't you show your proof for (weak) convexity?  Then we can try to point out where you can replace $\le$ by $<$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm assuming that $(x_k)$ is a bounded sequence, so that $f(y)$ is finite for all $y \in \Bbb R$.

Generally, for $a, b \in \Bbb R^n$ and $\lambda \in \Bbb R$ we have, with $\cdot$ denoting the scalar product:
$$
\Vert \lambda a + (1-\lambda) b \Vert^2 = \lambda^2 \Vert a \Vert^2 + 2 \lambda(1-\lambda) (a \cdot b)+  \lambda^2 \Vert b \Vert^2 \\
 = \lambda  \Vert a \Vert^2 +  \lambda \Vert b \Vert^2 - \lambda (1-\lambda)\left( \Vert a \Vert^2 - 2  (a \cdot b)+ \Vert b \Vert^2 \right)\\
= \lambda  \Vert a \Vert^2 +  \lambda \Vert b \Vert^2 - \lambda (1-\lambda) \Vert a-b \Vert^2 \, .
$$

Now let $y, z \in \Bbb R^n$, $y \ne z$, and $0<\lambda< 1$. For all $k$ we have
$$
 \Vert \lambda y + (1-\lambda) z - x_k \Vert^2 = 
\Vert \lambda(y-x_k) + (1-\lambda) (z-x_k) \Vert^2 \\
= \lambda \Vert y-x_k \Vert^2 + (1-\lambda) \Vert z-x_k \Vert^2
-  \lambda (1-\lambda) \Vert y-z \Vert^2 \, .
$$
It follows that
$$
 f(\lambda y + (1-\lambda) z) \le  \lambda f(y) + (1-\lambda) f(z) -  \lambda (1-\lambda) \Vert y-z \Vert^2 \\
 < \lambda f(y) + (1-\lambda) f(z)\, .
$$

Comment: Why $f(y)=f(z)=0$ otherwise ?

Comment: @AnasBOUALII: My original answer was indeed wrong. – Have a look at the new version, it should be correct now.

Comment: yeah, well i didnt get the second identity used, where u took $z$ diffrent from $y$.

Comment: @AnasBOUALII: I have applied the first identity with $a = y-x_k$ and $b=z-x_k$.

Comment: yeah that s obvious, but I asked how we prove it wasnt clair at first(the identity).

Comment: @AnasBOUALII: Which part is unclear? (There was a square missing in the first identity, that is fixed now.)

Comment: Now, its perfect, thank you.

Comment: @AnasBOUALII: You are welcome! – (Note that you can *accept* an answer if it solved your problem.)

Comment: Answer Accepted!

Answer (score 0):

we first prove that $g_k(x)=||x-x_k||^2$ is a convex function.

Then we will have $g_k(tx+(1-t)y)\leq tg_k(x)+(1-t)g_k(y)$ for all $t\in [0,1] $ and $x,y\in \mathbb{R^n}.$

which means $$||tx+(1-t)y-x_k|| \leq ||x-x_k||+ ||y-x_k||$$

then $$limsup_k||tx+(1-t)y-x_k|| \leq limsup_k||x-x_k||+ limsup_k||y-x_k||$$
Hence, $f$ is convex.

Comment: But after we pass to the limit all strict inequality become $\leq$.

Comment: @Masacroso: Anas *is* the OP. This might be a misunderstanding from my above comment. What I meant is that Anas adds his/her proof of weak convexity to the *question.*

Comment: @Martin lol, thanks, I didnt noticed. Yes, this must be written in the text body of the original question

Comment: This is not a complete ''answer", just the convexity of $f$.